# Which event (if any) does an iPhone "replace bad spelling" interaction trigger?

Tags: jquery, iphone, event-handling

I have some code that uses the jQuery keyup event to detect when a user has changed the text inside a textarea. When there have been no keystrokes for (say) three seconds, I POST the updated text to the server to update it.

A user on an iPhone points out that when he holds his finger on an underlined (i.e. badly spelled) word in the text box, and chooses 'Replace...' to pick the correct spelling, this does not trigger the keyup event.

Could a kind and knowledgeable person please let me know which events (if any) this sort of interaction triggers? I think I can figure out how to do this on a desktop browser, but I'm not so sure how to tackle this on a mobile.

And a customary apology if I have not phrased this correctly, or miscategorised it, or otherwise triggered an unwelcome event in your head :-) I did try to look this up, but ran out of ideas. Thank you.

Comment: To add to / clarify the existing linked answer, use the `input` event - in jquery, instead of `$(el).on("keyup",..` use `$(el).on("input",..`)